# Rename MongoDB 4.0.4 Database Name

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

Getting below error :

```
db.copyDatabase("old_db","new_db","localhost:27017");

WARNING: db.copyDatabase is deprecated. See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/copydb-clone-deprecation
{
        "note" : "Support for the copydb command has been deprecated. See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/copydb-clone-deprecation",
        "ok" : 1
}
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.0-compatibility/#copydb-and-clone-commands

I went to this link, but there's no solution regarding this.

Any leads would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Use mongodump and mongorestore or write a script using the drivers.